# Knowing if the code is compiled using Lazarus or Delphi

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, compilation, lazarus

I am trying to have a code which can be possible to be compiled by Lazarus and Delphi without changing it. But for that it would be necessary a conditional statement or something similar to check which compiler is being used.So is there any directive or anything that is possible to know if a code is being compiled with Lazarus or Delphi?

Comment: FreePascal compiler has (in its default mode) the `FPC` directive defined, check out e.g. this [`unofficial article`](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/FreePascal_detection_and_versioning).

Comment: The easiest way to answer this is to look at some open source code that target both compilers. For example, GR32. Lots of ifdef for `VERXXX` and then an ifdef for `FPC`. Learn from a good project like that.

Comment: Indy 10 targets Delphi, C++Builder, FreePascal/Lazarus, and .NET, so there are lots of useful IFDEFs and DEFINEs in its `IdCompilerDefines.inc` file.

Comment: Definately use `{$IFDEF FPC}`. In recent versions, Delphi has (finally) started defining its own `DCC` define as well: `{$IFDEF DCC}`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, good news, I'd vote for that as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question was provided in the comments, I'll just copy the core bit here:

*Use `{$IFDEF FPC}` to detect FreePascal*.

Comment: Unlike some other tags, let's prevent the q/a ratio of the Delphi from deteriorating. "No Delphi question shall be left behind", etc.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment in your comment, a lot of the deterioration of that rate has to do with the quality of the questions...

Comment: Perhaps (although there are definitely tags where the questions are worse), but this question is fine. Most of us just *know* this from after years of exposure to relevant source code, but it isn't documented in such a way that google will turn it up if you don't use the correct terminology.